# Java return type as Void and Object (More like Optional)

Tags: java, option-type

I would like to know if there is a way to implement interface method with void or Object?

For example...

> Interface

```
public interface MyInterface {
     public XXXXXXX myMethod();
}
```

And

> Implementation Class 1

```
public class MyClassOne implements MyInterface {
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("MyClassOne");
    }
}
```

> Implementation Class 2

```
public class MyClassTwo implements MyInterface {
     public String myMethod() {
         System.out.println("MyClassTwo");
         return "MyClassTwo";
     }
}
```

Comment: you may return String in the both cases, in the first one just return null (it will be ignored anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `MyInterface<T>` and the [`Void` type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) for the `void` case:

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
    T myMethod();
}

public class MyClassOne implements MyInterface<Void> {
    @Override
    public Void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("MyClassOne");
        return null;
    }
}

public class MyClassTwo implements MyInterface<String> {
     @Override
     public String myMethod() {
         System.out.println("MyClassTwo");
         return "MyClassTwo";
     }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, Thanks. why we need to return null in Void? Can I not use void. My main problem is I have Class1 already been implemented and I can't change method signature. My new class implementation Class2 has to return. But, both has to use same interface.

Comment: You cannot use void (small v) because it's not a type, so you have to use Void (big V) or you can use `Object` **and** return null. If you can not change your void-implementation then you cannot (AFAIK) do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

Answer (score 0):

In a general way, I think what you try to do is not a good idea because with it, you cannot program as interface since according the implementation you expect for a result or no.
Using a parameterized  type with a Void shows the problem.

Indeed, you cannot have a typed return based on a type more or less precise.
You handle an instance of Object type in the return.

For example :

```
MyInterface myInterface = new MyClassOne();
Object myMethod = myInterface.myMethod();
```

So, you must do instanceof or getClass to guess what to do...
You don't do OOP anylonger.
The interface loses its power.

If you need a method with a return and another without a return, create two methods. If you want to use a single method, you can keep the most broad (which one with the return type) and when you have no information to return,return null or a special value.

A method have to have a clear responsibility.